# youtube-dl | Download playlist in respective directory

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, youtube-dl

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and youtube-dl to download videos.
How can I download videos in respective directory?

e.g.
Playlist name is: MyPlaylist, that contains several videos

how can I download videos in directory like:
**MyPlaylist/index_title.ext**

Comment: have you really not considered specifying an `mv` command after,  to move the file where you want it to be

Comment: @barlop I wanted to do it on-the-go, with some inbuilt option in youtube-dl. Look at the accepted answer, that perfectly resolves my query.

Comment: Sure but you could have put in your question that you wanted to do it without mv, and using functionality of youtube-dl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you checked the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#filesystem-options)?  Specifically the `-o, --output` option.  Using that, you should be able to do:

```
youtube-dl -o '/home/me/%(playlist_title)s/%(playlist_index)s_%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

That said, please be sure to respect the owner's rights with any videos you use this program for.

Comment: Thanks, That saved me a lot of work. And I'll keep the disclaimer in mind.

Comment: @nerdwaller Can you update your answer to add a missing single quote at the end of the code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

See Output template examples. https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template-examples

```
# Download YouTube playlist videos in separate directory indexed by video order in a playlist
$ youtube-dl -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re

# Download all playlists of YouTube channel/user keeping each playlist in separate directory:
$ youtube-dl -o '%(uploader)s/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/user/TheLinuxFoundation/playlists
```

My example.

`youtube-dl -ci -o "~/dl.folder/%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" --write-sub --convert-subs srt -k --download-archive archive.txt --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/ https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzBGtBze1AIcDmRwD2ZjiAA`

> -o, --output TEMPLATE            Output filename template, see the "OUTPUT TEMPLATE" for all the info

~

> -c, --continue                   Force resume of partially downloaded files.
>                                        By default, youtube-dl will resume
>                                        downloads if possible.

~

> -i, --ignore-errors              Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a playlist

~

> --download-archive FILE          Download only videos not listed in the archive file. Record the IDs of all
>                                        downloaded videos in it.

~

> --proxy URL                      Use the specified HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS proxy. To enable SOCKS proxy, specify a proper
>                                        scheme. For example socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/. Pass in an empty string (--proxy "")
>                                        for direct connection

~

> --write-sub                      Write subtitle file

~

> -k, --keep-video                 Keep the video file on disk after the post-processing; the video is erased by
>                                        default

~

> --convert-subs FORMAT            Convert the subtitles to other format
>                                        (currently supported: srt|ass|vtt|lrc)

ref:

https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template

youtube-dl --help `(youtube-dl --version 2019.08.13)`

Answer (score 0):

I want to update the answer by adding the playlist links in a file. Then download each playlist in its respective folder .

```
youtube-dl -f best -o '%(playlist_title)s/%(playlist_index)s_%(title)s.%(ext)s' -a list_of_playlist_links.txt
```

This will create a folder for each playlist and download the playlist. The playlists will be saved in the same directory of the file list_of_playlist_links.txt